# Java Sockets - Data duplicated on last write

Tags: java, serversocket

I have the following code that I am using to send a file to a client:

```
private void sendFile(Socket client) throws Exception {
        byte[] data = new byte[4096];
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.txt");

        while (fis.read(data, 0, data.length) != -1) {
            dos.write(data);
        }

        fis.close();
        dos.close();
}
```

The problem that I'm finding is that the file sizes are different after transfer. Upon further investigation, I discovered that the files were being duplicated on the last `dos.write(data)`.

**Example:**

Original File:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Cras dictum diam neque, eu dictum sem efficitur ut.
Ut eu hendrerit risus.
In dapibus vel lectus at egestas.
```

Transferred File:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Cras dictum diam neque, eu dictum sem efficitur ut.
Ut eu hendrerit risus.
In dapibus vel lectus at egestas.
Ut eu hendrerit risus.
In dapib
```

I'm at wit's end here and I've already looked at hundreds of examples trying to fix this. I've tried `dos.flush()`, changing the read to `dos.read(data)`, and changing the `while` loop condition. I'm expecting to transfer very large files so I don't want to load a file all at once.

**EDIT:**

I have been using both `telnet` and `netcat` from the command line for testing the download.

Comment: You need to check return values from both read and write. The value from read tells you how much was read and can safely be written. The value from write tells you how much was written and might prompt a retry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this method

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#write(byte[],%20int,%20int)

and

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read(byte[],%20int,%20int)

> len - the maximum number of bytes read.

and returns

> the total number of bytes read into the buffer

You only want to write the amount of bytes that were read previously

so

```
  int br = -1;
  while ((br = fis.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
        dos.write(data, 0, br);
  }
```

Comment: your link should be to `InputStream` read. The root cause is that the poster assumed that call to read guarantees reading as many bytes as are passed in the third argument. Of course, it doesn't.

Comment: I think that OP assumed that the array would be cleared

Comment: which is also a problem with the question - there isn't any 'duplicate data'. you're just writing stuff you didn't actually read, over and over. and the reason you're doing that is you never checked how much you actually read.

Comment: no. you should be keeping track of what you read and writing just that.

Comment: With my solution it is not necessary, **but** it is also another possible solution

Comment: Thank both of you so much. Sorry for my lack of knowledge in Java. I only started a month or two ago.

Comment: i don't think it is. you'd be writing a bunch of nulls with `dos.write(data);` if you just cleared the array. it's not about clearing, it's about the contract of `read`.

Comment: Sure, the other side would also need to know how many bytes that are read. @pvg Thanks for your input

Comment: happy to help a little. when you see seemingly unexpected behaviour like that, check the javadoc of the calls you are making. it's usually quite thorough about details like that which might end up biting you in unexpected ways.

Comment: @ScaryWombat this code is working great, but i ran into a problem where the file contains two blank lines at its beginning and its causing the server to end the connection. I will post as a new question if you don't think that it's related to this code.

Comment: I can not see how it is related